# Javascript file sometimes truncated

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-chrome, iis-6

I have a Javascript library that loads with my web application (jqWidgets, in case anyone was wondering). However, a customer called because the app was not rendering correctly. When I compared the library file that is served to me vs the one that was being served to my customer, I found that the one being served to my customer is extremely truncated. This only happens when he uses the web app in Chrome; the library loads fine in IE 10. On my machine, however, the library does not get truncated in neither Chrome nor IE. Is there some setting in Chrome that maybe limiting the size of the Javascript file being served to it?

**About the application**

- ASP.NET 4.0 Web Application
- Running on IIS 6.0
- Both computers running Windows 7

Comment: could have refreshed mid-load or gotten an undetected net error that got cached. clear caches and try again, this is not a common or expected problem.

Comment: I've tried clearing the caches. No joy. This happens after refreshing the page multiple times as well.